# Есть ли готовый проект браузера для С++Builder 6?

Tags: c++builder

Нужен готовый файл *.bpr — заготовка для браузера, где можно найти такой?

Comment: Что значит "заготовка для браузера"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По характеру вопроса предположу, что автору хватит с головой компонента `TCppWebBrowser` с палитры **Internet**.

Comment: Да, спасибо, подошел

Answer (score 0):

Примеры разработки браузера ести у А.Я.Архангельского "Программирование в C++ Builder 6" изд. Бином 2004 и В.Шамиса "Borland C++ Builder 6" изд. Питер 2004г.